# Designing a time-based system to trigger a certain time before an event

Tags: events, timer, architecture, backend

I'd like to design a system that looks like the following:

- At time `T`, there will be an event `E` happening
- I define a delay `D`, and some action `A`
- At time `T - D` (`D` seconds before `E` happens), my system does the action `A`

My problems are that if I store the time `T - D` when the action and delay `(A, D)` is defined, and `T` changes, then I will have to update that stored time. This may cause some inconsistencies to appear in my system as I will have to think about all events that should be updated everytime I touch an event's lifespan.

If I decide to not store `T - D`, then the only solution I see is to constantly check for further events. If I have a cron job running every hour, that cron job will have to take all events that have not happened, calculate the `current time + D`, and check it against `T`. This probably causes a lot of useless computations.

Is there a standard approach to tackling such a problem ? I don't want to be forced to say that `T` cannot be changed if that's not completely necessary. I've been researching terms like events-based architecture but I can't seem to find proper answers, maybe I use the wrong searches.

A good example of that is Stripe's "trial_will_end" event, that is triggered 3 days before a user's trial ends. This 3 days delay is however fixed, and I could not find out what happens if I extend a trial after this event has been emitted. I guess that depending on their implementation it will trigger twice, or not.

I do hope my question is clear, if not, do not hesitate to ask questions and I will edit my post.